# The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

Android studio >> Terminal >> `gradlew clean`

When I do this operation, I encounter a problem:

> Error:Could not open cp_init remapped class cache for
>   561n9x1cpuxa3s0gicmaiwd5p
>   (C:D:\work_space\offic_space\GoGal_AS>gradlew clean The
>   JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and is
>   scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Incremental java compilation is
>   an incubating feature. The TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been
>   deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use
>   TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead. :clean UP-TO-DATE
>
> Building 50% > :app:clean

It stays at 50% all the time. Can anyone help me?